Filter table in Phonograph2 based on one of multiple PK
I am trying to bring filtered data into my Foundry Slate app. For this I need to query a Phonograph2 table which has 3 columns as PK and one with values. I am using the Table Search Service with Search endpoint. I tried with term, terms, match and it either returns invalid argument or 0 hits.
{
  "tableRids": [
    "ri.phonograph2.main.table.27e7b8b7-17f1-4cc6-8162-760be5722b32"
  ],
  "filter": {
    "type": "terms",
    "terms": {
      "field": "S_ID",
      "terms": ["S10001"]
    }
  }
}


The table has 4 columns: 3 PK (S_ID, N_TYPE, N_YR) and N_VAL. The code above returns 0 hits.

Check this out:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/references-writeback/#querystring-filter
Anyway, I use it like this, but you can add AND / OR to add:
{   
"tableRids": [
         "{{phono_data_manual}}"   ],   "filter": {
         "type": "queryString",
         "queryString": {
           "queryString": "date_1:xxx* AND cc:xxx"
         }   
} 
}

